# Почему разный результат проверки списка C#?

Tags: c#, .net, list, ping

прошу помочь сообщество с программой
Эта программа предназначена для массовой проверки доступности IP адресов.
Загрузка адресов происходит в ListBox "Загруженные IP" из txt файла, после нажатия кнопки "Ping" IP должны пропинговаться и доступные адреса добавиться в другой ListBox "Доступные IP", а недоступные записаться в Log (пока не реализовано), однако, несмотря на частичную работу программы -- результат непредсказуемый.
В ListBox "Доступные IP" либо не попадают адреса совсем (все адреса в списке 100% доступны), либо после многократного нажатия на "Ping" попадают в разном количестве.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
namespace AOConfig
{
    public partial class MassScript : Form
    {
        
        public MassScript()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OpenFileBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SourceList.Items.Clear();
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text Documents(*.txt)|*.txt", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string[] switchList = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName,Encoding.UTF8);
                    SourceList.Items.AddRange(switchList);
                    TotalCount_label.Text = SourceList.Items.Count.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        private void StartPingBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Ping switchPing = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply = null;
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
            options.DontFragment = true;
            // options.Ttl = 64;
            int timeout = 100;
            foreach (var Item in SourceList.Items)
            {
                string Host = SourceList.GetItemText(Item);
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Host);
                pingReply = switchPing.Send(Host, timeout, buffer, options);

                if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    LiveList.Items.Add(Host);
                    LiveCount_label.Text = LiveList.Items.Count.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если у вас статус не равен `Success`, то вы делаете `break`, что означает полный выход из цикла, тут скорей всего вы хотели `continue` использовать (да и он в вашем случае будет бессмыслен, ибо после него нет какого либо кода.

Comment: Разве это не правильно? Цикл прервётся, если один из адресов недоступен, но в списке все адреса доступны, поэтому все адреса пройдя проверку должны попасть из списка "Загруженные IP" в список "Доступные IP", т.к. пока идет проверка только доступных адресов.

Comment: Ну допустим у вас идут адреса в списке `1.1.1.1`, `2.2.2.2` ну и `3.3.3.3`. Адрес `1.1.1.1` доступен, цикл пошел дальше, проверяет `2.2.2.2`, а он вдруг недоступен, дальше по вашей логике, коду не нужно проверять `3.3.3.3`. По этой причине у вас выведет в список доступных Ip `1.1.1.1` и все. Вы уверены, что именно такой результат хотите?

Comment: Да, всё верно, но пока требуется только 

после нажатия кнопки "Ping" IP должны пропинговаться и доступные адреса добавиться в другой ListBox "Доступные IP", а недоступные записаться в Log (пока не реализовано)

Comment: Ну тогда у вас очень странный подход, если вы часть доступных адресов просто выбрасываете в помойку, то тогда какой смысл в этой проверке на доступность? Дайте список этих ip текстом, а то с картинки переписывать не очень хочется, проверю у себя ваш код.

Comment: Очень вам благодарна, перепроверила доступность IP руками, некоторые были недоступны, но после удаления нерабочих адресов лучше не стало.
8.8.8.8
5.255.255.77
94.100.180.201
91.228.155.94
104.26.12.200
212.193.158.156
82.202.213.210
5.187.1.122
185.65.56.149
31.13.92.36
87.240.137.158
195.54.213.252
185.253.217.253
144.208.108.215

Answer (score 0):

Для работы в публичных сетях, необходимо поставить int timeout побольше, цикл не обрывать.
Рабочий код

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace AOConfig
{
    public partial class MassScript : Form
    {
        
        public MassScript()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OpenFileBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SourceList.Items.Clear();
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text Documents(*.txt)|*.txt", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string[] switchList = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName,Encoding.UTF8);
                    SourceList.Items.AddRange(switchList);
                    TotalCount_label.Text = SourceList.Items.Count.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        private void StartPingBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Ping switchPing = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply = null;
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
            options.DontFragment = true;
            // options.Ttl = 64;
            int timeout = 1000; // время ожидания ответа 1 сек
            foreach (var Item in SourceList.Items)
            {
                string Host = SourceList.GetItemText(Item);
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Host);
                pingReply = switchPing.Send(Host, timeout, buffer, options);

                if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    LiveList.Items.Add(Host);
                    LiveCount_label.Text = LiveList.Items.Count.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    continue; // не прерываем цикл
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```